# plotting simplex method in Maxima

Tags: gnuplot, maxima

im having trouble plotting the results of simplex method used for linear programing in Maxima

i used

```
minimize_lp(-4*x-5*y,[5*x+4*y<=40, x+4*y<=32, 5*x<=30]);
```

to solve the problem but now i need to plot this

tried this:

```
wxplot2d(minimize_lp(-4*x-5*y,[5*x+4*y<=40, x+4*y<=32, 5*x<=30]),[x,-10,10],[y,-10,10]);
```

all i get is "expression evaluates to non-numeric value everywhere in plotting range" and "nothing to plot" messages

i dont really use Maxima, im not very familiar with it,
its an assigment for a course, any help would be great

Comment: When you minimize a function, you get a solution of the form `[value, [conditions]]`. In your case it is `[-91/2,[y=15/2,x=2]]`. What are you trying to plot? It's not a function, and not a set of points.

Comment: yes, [-91/2,[y=15/2,x=2]] is the optimal solution if im not mistaking. but this problem has other solutions, which are not optimal. im suposed to plot a set of points of all possible solutions

Comment: Then you nave to choose another approach because this function either gives only one solution, or doesn't give any.

Comment: any idea how? ive been trying to figure it out but i got nothing. how can i plot inequalities?

Answer (score 2):

### Graphical solution for a linear optimization problem subject to constraints

To plot the inequalities and the feasible set I did the following:

### Step 1 – solving algebraically using *minimize_lp()*

---

```
load("simplex")$
minimize_lp(
    -4*x-5*y,[
     5*x+4*y<=40, 
     x+4*y<=32, 
     5*x<=30,
     x>=0,y>=0
   ]
);
```

which yields

```
%o2) [-91/2,[y=15/2,x=2]]
```

### Step 2 – extracting the coordinates of the optimizing point from %o2

```
soln: %o2$
c4sol: soln[2]$
x_c: rhs(c4sol[2])$ 
y_c: rhs(c4sol[1])$
pOpt: [x_c,y_c];
```

This outputs

```
(%o7) [2,15/2]
```

the coordinates of the optimizing point *pOpt* in a list that we later need for plotting.

### Step 3 – defining the feasible set

We know from *minimize_lp()* that f(x,y) is minimized at (x=2,y=15/2) with
f=-91/2. So we rewrite the target function as -4*x-5*y=-91/2

```
tfm: solve(-4*x-5*y=-91/2,y)$
```

Next we use the restriction *r1,r2,r3* to define the the bounderies of the feasible set by turning the inequalities into equalities and solving for the dependent variables:

```
r1: solve(5*x+4*y=40,y)$
r2: solve(x+4*y=32,y)$
r3: solve(5*x=30,x)$
```

We then create a list L containing:

```
L: [ev(y,tfm), ev(y,r1), ev(y,r2), ev(x,r3)];
```

which yields:

```
(%o12) [-(8*x-91)/10,-(5*x-40)/4,-(x-32)/4,6]
```

### Step 4 – The plots

We use *plot2d()* for quick'n'dirty sketches:

```
plot2d(L,[x,1.5,5.25],[y,5,8.25])$
```

For the final plot we use *draw2d*

```
draw2d(
proportional_axes=xy ,
    xrange = [1.5,5.25],
    yrange = [5.00,8.25],
point_type = filled_circle, point_size=1.25,
     color = black,
          points(pOpt),
          label(["pOpt = (2,15/2)", 2.50, 7.65]),
       key = "tfMin=-91/2",
line_width = 2,
     color = steelblue4,
          explicit(ev(y,tfm ), x,0,12.25),
       key = "r1",
line_width = 1.5,
     color = DeepPink3,
          explicit(ev(y,r1), x,0,12.25),
       key = "r2", 
line_width = 1.5,
     color = cyan4,
          explicit(ev(y,r2), x,0,12.25),
       key = "r3", 
line_width = 1.5,
     color = orange,
          explicit(ev(x,r3), x,0,12.25),
       key = "feasible set",
    border = false,
fill_color = LightPink2,
          polygon([[3.20,6],[2,7.5],[3.9,6]])
)$
```

[image: Plot of the feasible set]

Hope this helps, after all these years.

Cheers
Tilda